# Openlayers Polygon Force Label Option

Tags: openlayers

Can anyone suggest a solution for forcing a polygon label to always be displayed?

See the official example here:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html

If you zoom in to a polygon, the label does not move, it is always shown only at the chosen point. Instead, it would be good to force the label to always show at the centre of the visible part of the feature.

It seems it might be possible to do by using a geometry function, but only if it's possible to clip features by the current extent.

If anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this, I would be very interested.

Thanks

Comment: You may use JSTS library to get the intersection of your view MBR and the geometry you want to label.  Here is an example of jsts usage-->https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html .  The function you have to use is here --> https://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/jsts.geom.Geometry.html#intersection

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this looks like what I need.